# Convert dB to ohms

Tags: resistance, vna, decibel

I did some impedance measurements in high frequencies using a VNA.
I did not pay attention to the format of the measured values that were in dB so it is now to late for me to reperform measurements.

I would like to know how to convert dB to ohms.

Comment: You can't, directly!  dB is a ratio of two powers.  Ohm is resistance, or impedance in this case.

Comment: @SteveSh So there's no solution?

Comment: Not if you're really trying to convert a power measurement into ohms.  If you know the voltage that corresponds to that power measurement, then yes, you could.  But not with just the information you provided.

Comment: Do you only have magnitude of S11 in dB, or do you also have the phase of S11?

Comment: I also had the phase @ThePhoton

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably what you're measuring is return loss, or S11, in dB, of the load that you want the resistance of.

Let's assume you're measuring a pure resistor at the reference plane, so S11 will have a phase angle of 0 or 180 degrees.

Convert the return loss R in dB to the reflection coefficient \$\sigma=10^{\frac{-R}{20}}\$

So a return loss of 10dB is a reflection coefficient of about 0.3, or 0.31 if you want more digits.

Now convert the reflection coefficient to an impedance ratio with respect to the VNA impedance, \$ratio=\frac{1+\sigma}{1-\sigma}\$. This is 1.9 for the -10dB S11 we're illustrating.

If the VNA is working in 50 Ω system (almost all are), then if we just take the magnitude of \$\sigma\$, your 1.9 ratio means you have a resistance connected to the port of either 26 Ω or 95 Ω. To tell which, you need the sign of \$\sigma\$, or the phase angle of your S11 dBs.

Interestingly, this ratio is also equal to the VSWR of the load. You may find some calculators online that will go in a single step from your return loss to VSWR.

If you're not at the reference plane, you'll have some other phase, and so you're measuring a complex impedance. Use the same equation for impedance \$ratio=\frac{1+\sigma}{1-\sigma}\$, and the complex numbers will work their magic. If you do have a pure resistance on a transmission line, then most VNAs will allow you to offset the reference plane by some electrical length, to get back to a real S11.

Comment: Nice answer.  I want to hear from the OP that he was measuring S11 with his VNA.

Comment: isn't sigma complex? If so, wouldn't that mean that the load can have *any* value between 26 Ohm and 95 Ohm, provided the correct phase?

Comment: @tobalt sigma complex means you're measuring an inductor, or a capacitor, or a resistor offset by some length of transmission line, ie the impedance is complex. As the OP asked for ohms, I was assuming that he was measuring a resistor, at the reference plane, but of course assumptions make an ass...

Comment: @Neil_UK The plot I had in my mind, was indeed e.g. a capacitor's or inductor's (absolute) impedance vs. frequency curve, which is usually in Ohms. But yeah, we can guess all day :)